# Django channel consumers of multiple channels send data to websocket clients but all data is sent to lastly connected websocket client

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I use django channels 3.0.0 and websocket using angular.
But users connect to django websocket and they are in their own rooms respectively.
And when I want to send the event to connected users outside of consumers, I used the following code.

```
all_users = list(Member.objects.filter(is_active = True).values_list('id', flat = True))
for user_id in all_users:
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        "chat_{}".format(user_id),            
        { "type": "tweet_send", "message": "tweet created" }
    )
```

And in consumers.py, my consumer class's chat_message function

```
async def tweet_send(self, event):
    content = event['message']

    # Send message to WebSocket
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        "type": "MESSAGE",
        "data": content
    }))
```

And this "self.send" function is meant to be sent to all connected users respectively, but when I run the code, the all data are sent to only one user who has connected the last time.
I don't know why. If anyone knows the reason, please help me.

Comment: `django-channels` has released bug fixes in `3.0.1` and `3.0.2`. I'd suggest to try with version `3.0.2`. If the problem persists, try to disable `django-debug-toolbar` if ever you have it in your INSTALLED_APPS, it tends to suck exceptions from django-channels preventing them from being printed if runserver logs. If the problem persists, I'd file a bug report in django-channels.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in version `3.0.0`. It was [reported](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1566) and fixed in `3.0.1`.